# How to link drop down cells in 2 different worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a spreadsheet for my work and I want to create a drop down list which have to contain "Canceled","ordered","accepted".(I know how to create this drop down list). Now I want the exact thing in another sheet. (This is easy to do using the equal sign). I want to give the user the ability to change the values of these cell from both sheets, in a way that when someone changes the value in Cell A1 in sheet A the value in cell A1 sheet B changes automatically and when someone changes the value in Cell A1 in sheet B the value in cell A1 sheet A changes as well.

How can I do setup this sort of link between two cells?

Comment: I believe that what you want can't be done without utilizing VBA-code. Is this a valid option for you?

Comment: That's called a circular reference and Excel won't allow that with formulas.  Also, a cell cannot contain both a formula and an entry.  You would have to use it for one or the other (an entry would overwrite the formula).  You would need VBA, as eirikdaude mentioned.

Comment: How can I do this then? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that with formulas. Because that is a circular reference error (they would be infinitely changing the values)

However you can create a third cell somewhere else, which will be source for cells in sheet A and B. So whenever you change this third cell, it will be reflected in those two cells.